# Extract images from launch file (storyboard) for each device and orientation

Tags: ios, orientation, uistoryboard, launchimage, launch-screen

I've created a storyboard as [launch image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) for the start up of the application.

Is it possible to get png images out of the launch screen for each device and orientation automatically? I don't need the status bar included.

Then I wouldn't need to create extra launch images for iOS 7. Is this possible?

Comment: Would be a nice feature to have in Xcode.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Filled out an enhancment request at Apple's bug reporter tool. Case No. 19249885.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is impossible to do it automatically.

You can launch your app on each simulator type for iOS 8 (iPad, iPhone with different sizes) and snapshot simulator when it showing launch screen by CMD+S shortcut.

You will get snapshots on your Mac desktop folder, and then you can add it as launch images

Comment: I already thought something like this. The problem with this approach is the status bar. I have a special background image which is not easy to reconstruct if you like to remove the text from the status bar. Perhaps it is possible to deactivate the status bar on launch. It would still be much work to get the images out.

Comment: Disable status bar during splash in project settings :-) `Status bar is initially hidden` in the project info settings